# SQL Server Computed Column value for GEOMETRY data type

Tags: sql-server, geometry

I have got a table in an SQL Server 2008 R2 database. It contains X, Y and Shape columns for storing numeric(38, 8) for Longitude and Latitude and Computed Column for Geometry type. The idea is whenever X and Y are inserted, Shape column should automatically be filled with the correct Geometry data.

X and Y are populated. However, I have been unsuccessful in specifying the Shape column. In SQL Server Management Studio, it gave me errors of failing validating formula when I populated either of the following codes in Formula of Computed Column Specification:

```
(STGeomFromText('POINT (' + CAST([x] as varchar(32)) + ' ' + CAST([y] as varchar(32)) + ')', 4283))

OR

([STGeomFromText]('POINT (' + CAST([x] as varchar(32)) + ' ' + CAST([y] as varchar(32)) + ')', 4283))
```

Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks!

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was actually then enlightened by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572806/trigger-for-insert-and-update-on-same-table).

Hope it helps to anybody else who has the same question.

```
ALTER TABLE LOCATION
ADD Shape AS (CONVERT(GEOMETRY, CASE WHEN x<> 0
                                    AND y<> 0
                               THEN GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT('
                                                          + CONVERT(VARCHAR, x)
                                                          + ' '
                                                          + CONVERT(VARCHAR, y)
                                                          + ')', 4238)
                               ELSE NULL
                          END))
```

Answer (score 4):

A slightly better solution:

```
ALTER TABLE LOCATION
ADD Shape AS (CONVERT(GEOMETRY, CASE WHEN x IS NOT NULL AND y IS NOT NULL
                               THEN GEOMETRY::Point(x,y,4238)
                               ELSE NULL
                          END))
```

This saves two unnecessary converts (from int to varchar) and also allows points at which the equator (0° latitude) and the prime meridian (0° longitude) intersect to also be considered "valid".